# Looping an input in Python

Tags: python

I am creating a list with all 12 months of the year. I want to create a loop that will ask as input ("Enter a number) and store all these inputs into an empty list (promptList).

Here is some of my code. I keep getting a TypeError saying at least 1 input is expected.

```
monthsList = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July",
          "Augist", "September", "October", "November", "December"]

promptList = []

for x in range(13):
    num = float(input("Enter rainfall amount for ", monthsList[x], ": "))
    promptList.append(num)
    if x == 13:
        break
    print(promptList)
```

Comment: Not “at least”, but *at most* one argument to the function `input`! You’re passing three arguments to `input`, which it doesn’t accept. Concatenate the string and pass a single string instead.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the message error is a bit different, and solves it pretty quickly:

```
TypeError: input expected at most 1 argument, got 3here
```

The input() function expects only one argument - the message prompt. You provided 3 of them (a string, a list element, a string). So refactoring your message to f-string does the job:

```
num = float(input(f"Enter rainfall amount for {monthsList[x]},: "))
```

Comment: Such a simple error! Thank you. Can you explain what the "{ }" do?

Comment: In f-strings, {} denotes part of the string, that should be evaluated by the interpreter as regular code - you can put variable name there, or any other code